# Get all children on the stage / parent Object

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I get a list of all the children (Sprites) on the stage of my Document Class OR how can I get a list (length) of all the children (Sprites) of a parent (Sprite)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One idea is that you could write a helper function that will do the work for you.

```
public function getChildrenOf(target:DisplayObjectContainer):Array
{
   var children:Array = [];

   for (var i:uint = 0; i < target.numChildren; i++)
      children.push(target.getChildAt(i));

   return children;
}
```

Comment: Note, that if the target is set to `stage`, then it will include root, as root is a child of stage.  This may, or may not be what you want.

Comment: You could also call getChildrenOf recursively to get all grandchildren, greatgrand children etc:. something like: children.push(getChildrenOf(target.getChildAt(i)));